# Using the Material UI Link component with the Next.JS Link Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using Material-UI with Next.js.  I would like to use the [Material-UI Link component](https://material-ui.com/components/links/#api) so that I can access to the `variant` and other [Material UI related API props](https://material-ui.com/api/link/).  At the same time, I need to use the [Next.js Link component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) for linking between pages.

I am wondering, how do I use the two of them together so that I can get the linking benefits of the Next.js Link component along with the styling benefits of the MaterialUI link component.

Ideally, I'd like to create my own Link component that combines the two of them into my single component so that I can use it anywhere I need to within my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

##### Before Next.js 13

You can wrap the Material UI link with the Next.js one. This will provide the benefits of using both.

```js
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import { Link as MUILink } from '@mui/material';

// ...

<NextLink href="/" passHref>
    <MUILink variant="body2">Your Link</MUILink>
</NextLink>
```

##### From Next.js 13

See [Shikyo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74419666/1870780) for a solution that works with the reworked `next/link` component in Next.js 13.

Comment: Thanks -- this looks good.  Is there any difference between doing it this way and Rajiv's solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66227329/7477670?

Comment: I guess there's this bit: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs. You'll probably need to add the ref forwarding capability to Next.js `Link` if you use that approach.

Comment: As of nextjs 13 this no longer works as expected

Comment: @Shikyo I'll add a note to my answer to make that clear.

Comment: This will lead to a hydration error in Next.js as <a> tags will be nested

Answer (score 24):

I disagree with all the accepted answers. This is what I found to be the most succinct and clear.

```
<Button // MUI Button
  href="/employees"
  LinkComponent={Link} // NextJS Link
>
  Manage Employees
</Button>
```

This pattern works on most (all?) MUI components.

Comment: Note that you can omit `component="a"` when using `LinkComponent={Link}`.

Comment: Actually it caused an error `Error: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with `href` of `/home` but only one child is supported ...`

Comment: It breaks client side navigation

Answer (score 24):

As of NextJS 13 `'next/link'` exposes `a` by default, meaning you no longer have to render an anchor element inside the link component. This makes integration with MUI a lot easier

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const LinkBehaviour = forwardRef(function LinkBehaviour(props, ref) {
    return <NextLink ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiLink: {
            defaultProps: {
                component: LinkBehaviour
            }
        },
        MuiButtonBase: {
            defaultProps: {
                LinkComponent: LinkBehaviour
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can import and use `'@mui/material/Link'` like you do normally.

Alternatively can you set the component when using the link:

```
<Link component={LinkBehaviour} href="/go-here">
    Click me!
</Link>
```

There might be some caveats to this approach, so far this is working for me. It also seems to handle external links properly although there might be some overhead there.

Comment: Why don't you simply do: `component: NextLink`
[Ref is already forwarded](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/link.tsx#L240).

Comment: @BiasInput Well spotted, I thought that as well but doing so gives a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` exception. Not sure why.

Comment: @Shikyo on my side it seems to work without any exception. <Link component={NextLink} href="/auth/sign-in"> aaa </Link>

Comment: @ThomasRamé What about when you configure it like that in the `createTheme` function?

Comment: I get TS errors with this code but it's valid JS. TS issue in MUI is being tracked here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/27593. For now, I'm using `// @ts-ignore`

Answer (score 20):

**Updated Answer**

Before Next.js 13

```
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';

// ...

<NextLink href="/" passHref>
    <Link variant="body2">Your Link</Link>
</NextLink>
```

From Next.js 13

```
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';

<Link href="/" component={NextLink} variant="body2">
  Your link
</Link>
```

Answer (score 13):

`Link` accepts a `component` prop that combines both properties. It works perfectly with `react-router`, might also work well with netxjs `Link`.

```
<Link component={NextjsLink}>Link Text</Link>
```

Here change the import name of the nextjs link.

[Related Material-ui Documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly -- the above code would function BOTH as a Material-UI Link component AND a NextJS Link component (meaning that I can use all props and other related behavior.

Comment: I guess so.. But I'm not sure as I haven't worked with nextjs but I've used this method react-router a lot and it works fine there. give it a try..

Comment: Had the same problem with the Button component from Material UI. It was not accepting ```component``` property because looks like it were not declared. This solved the issue (added component property to the ```Buton.d.ts```): 

    ```component?: Function;```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with NextJS, at least not as simply as described in this answer. Doing this with a Next Link results in this runtime error `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`. The accepted answer does work though.

Comment: @timgcarlson That's the caveat I mention in a comment to my answer: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs. You need to add the ref forwarding capability to Next.js `Link` if you use this approach.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid Ref warnings and some errors, I had to do this.

```
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { Link as MuiLink } from '@mui/material';

const Link = forwardRef((props: any, ref:any)=>{
  const {href} = props;
  return <NextLink href={href} passHref >
          <MuiLink ref={ref} {...props}/>
          </NextLink>
})
Link.displayName = 'CustomLink';
```

This is how I used it.

```
<CardActionArea LinkComponent={Link} href={'/home'}>
...
</CardActionArea>
```

Comment: This was the only solution that let me define `Link` separately in a component library and also pass down CSS styling through `sx`.

Comment: This worked for me, I did the same for MuiButton as well. But I did need to add `legacyBehavior` alongside the `passHref`.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript version of the Next.js Link and Material UI Link/Button (v5) with `forwardRef` can be found at https://gist.github.com/kachar/028b6994eb6b160e2475c1bb03e33e6a

Adding some of the components here for brevity

```
import React, { forwardRef, Ref } from 'react'
import Link, { LinkProps } from 'next/link'
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@mui/material'

type LinkRef = HTMLButtonElement
type NextLinkProps = Omit<ButtonProps, 'href'> &
  Pick<LinkProps, 'href' | 'as' | 'prefetch' | 'locale'>

const LinkButton = ({ href, as, prefetch, locale, ...props }: LinkProps, ref: Ref<LinkRef>) => (
  <Link href={href} as={as} prefetch={prefetch} locale={locale} passHref>
    <Button ref={ref} {...props} />
  </Link>
)

export default forwardRef<LinkRef, NextLinkProps>(LinkButton)
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link as LinkMUI, LinkProps as LinkMUIProps } from "@mui/material";
import NextLink, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from "next/link";

export type LinkProps = Omit<LinkMUIProps, "href" | "classes"> &
  Pick<NextLinkProps, "href" | "as" | "prefetch">;

export const Link = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  ({ href, as, prefetch, ...props }, ref) => (
    <NextLink href={href} as={as} prefetch={prefetch} passHref>
      <LinkMUI ref={ref} {...props} />
    </NextLink>
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me, using Next with TS, MUi v5

in theme.ts

```
declare module "@mui/material/Typography" {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    "button-emphasis": true;
  }
}
```

...

```
  const theme = createTheme(theme, {
      components: {
        MuiLink: {
          variants: [
            {
              props: { variant: "button-emphasis" },
              style: {                            
                backgroundColor: darken(theme.palette.blue.main,1),        
                "&:hover": {
                  backgroundColor: darken(theme.palette.blue.main,0.35),
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
```

in component

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { Link } from "@mui/material";
```

...

```
<Link component={NextLink} variant="button-emphasis" href="/contact">
Text
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

for typescript:

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from "next/link";
const LinkBehaviour = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  function LinkBehaviour(props, ref) {
    return <NextLink {...props} />;
  }
);
```

and bump to [@spencer5051's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389857/7084100)

Answer (score 0):

The best anwser I found was this

We can create a custom component using Next Link and MUI Link

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import MuiLink from "@mui/material/Link";
import MuiButton from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function Link({ type, href, children, ...props }) {
  if (type === "link" || !type) {
    return (
      <NextLink href={href} passHref>
        <MuiLink {...props}>{children}</MuiLink>
      </NextLink>
    );
  } else if (type === "button") {
    return (
      <NextLink href={href} passHref>
        <MuiButton {...props}>{children}</MuiButton>
      </NextLink>
    );
  }
```

And then, where you wanna use, you can use like this:

```
import Link from "../path/to/link";
// Later...
<Link type="button" href="/somewhere">Yay!</Link>
```

Is the best solution by far...

Credits: codingjlu

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to create custom component here is code

```
const NextLinkButton = ({ ...props }: Omit<ButtonProps, 'href'> & Pick<LinkProps, 'href'>): JSX.Element => {
      return <Button LinkComponent={Link} {...props} href={props.href.toString()} />;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
In my case, I wanted to create my 'CustomLink' components in the 'components' folder and export it to wherever I wanted to import and use them.

/components/CustomLink.js

```
import { Link as MuiLink } from '@mui/material';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const CustomLink = forwardRef(({ onClick, href, name }, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MuiLink href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref} target='_blank'>
        {name}
      </MuiLink>
    </>
  );
});

export default CustomLink;
```

then you can use this CustomLink component, such as

/pages/search/[search].js

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import CustomLink from '@/components/CustomLink';


export default function Search() {
  return(
    <>
      <Link href='your_href_link' passHref legacyBehavior>
        <CustomLink name='read preview' onClick={() => console.log('clicked!')} />
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

References:

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link
2. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/link/

Answer (score -1):

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const router = useRouter();

<Button onClick={() => router.push("/home")}>Home</Button>
```

This worked for me. The app doesn't refresh either.

Answer (score -5):

Had the same problem with the `Button` component from `Material UI`. It was not accepting `component` property because looks like it was not declared. This solved the issue (added component property to the `Buton.d.ts`): `component?: Function;`

Here the solution: [image: Buton.d.ts file modified]

and boom no error anymore:

[image: Index file no error]

Comment: making changes inside the `node_modules` folder is not a wise decision as it is not under git tracking and every time you run `npm i`  or deploy this project, it gonna install new packages.

Comment: @Rajiv Yes - that's true. But what could another solution be. Maybe create an issue at Material UI github?

Comment: Copy-paste snippet: 

```/**
     * Component property for Next Link
*/
    component?: Function;```

Comment: I know this seems like necro-bumping but if anyone's looking to do something similar, [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) is a great solution for this.

Comment: @kiyui Great to know!! Thanks for enriching the comments here!